# Why does my Ubuntu 17.10 lock screen show "file 2 new notifications"

Tags: lock-screen

When I move my mouse or hit enter to wake up Ubuntu the lock screen shows "files: 2 new notifications" and "Backups: 1 new notification" but after I enter my password there are no notifications to be found. Where are these notifications to be found?  Can't take a screen-shot before I login but it's the screen with picture of Grand Canyon and time and date.

Answer (score 15):

I found my answer by moving the mouse pointer up to the top of the screen by the current day and time.  Click on it and a drop down appears with a calendar on the right and notifications on the left.

Comment: A fine point, the day/time at the top of the screen is the screen *after* you've logged in.